# I have multiple labels how do I go to loop through them programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have multiple labels (label1,label2,label3,etc) I want to loop through them programmatically. I have done this in vb.net but the same does not work in C#.

I get the error

> An explicit conversion exist.

What is the right way to do this?

Below is the code for VB.net which works but it does not for C#

C#

```
UserControl uc1 = tabPage1.Controls["lblprice" + control];
```

vb.net

```
Do While count < 18

        Dim uc1 As UserControl = TabPage3.Controls("AbsenceUC" & count.ToString & "")
        Dim TxtEmployeeID As TextBox = uc1.Controls("txtEmpId")
        Dim TxtAbsenteeCode As TextBox = uc1.Controls("TextBox2")
        Dim txttext As String = TxtEmployeeID.Text
Loop
```

Comment: A Label is a `ContentControl` not a `UserControl` so use `ContentControl uc1 = tabPage1.Controls["lblprice" + control];`

Comment: Use an array instead of the `Controls` property.

Comment: @slvnperron thanks for the answer. I tried the code as you suggested but it does not recognize "ContentControl". Error : The type or .....'ContentControl' any ideas ?

Comment: @omachu23 well you can use `Label` directly then. I thought you had a WPF application.. `Label uc1 = tabPage1.Controls["lblprice" + control] as Label;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all of the labels on that form with this code:

```
var labels = tabPage1.Controls.OfType<Label>();
foreach (Label lbl in labels)
{
    // lbl.Content = "Do stuff here..."
}
```

The error is because you need to cast the result.

```
Label uc1 = (Label)tabPage1.Controls["lblprice" + control];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all controls like this

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
  {
            if (c is Label) // Here check if the control is label 
            {
                c.BackColor = Color.Red; // you code goes here

            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(count < 18)
{      
    //Find string key 
    var uc1 = tabPage3.Controls.Find("AbsenceUC", true).Where(x=> YOUR WHERE CLAUSE HERE).Single();

    //Cast your controls to TextBoxes
    TextBox TxtEmployeeID = uc1.Controls.Find("txtEmpId", true).Single() as TextBox;
    TextBox TxtAbsenteeCode = uc1.Controls.Find("TextBox2", true).Single() as TextBox;
    String txttext = TxtEmployeeID.Text;
}
```